Index definition query
I want to get the Index definition with all included columns in the index using SQL query.
Below query doesn't seems to be working, any help would be appreciated.
WITH IndexInfo AS (
    SELECT 
        t.name AS TableName,
        i.name AS IndexName,
        i.index_id,
        STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + c.name
            FROM sys.index_columns ic
            JOIN sys.columns c ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
            WHERE ic.object_id = i.object_id 
            AND ic.index_id = i.index_id 
            AND ic.is_included_column = 0  -- Key columns only
            ORDER BY ic.key_ordinal
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS KeyColumns,
        STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + c.name
            FROM sys.index_columns ic
            JOIN sys.columns c ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
            WHERE ic.object_id = i.object_id 
            AND ic.index_id = i.index_id 
            AND ic.is_included_column = 1  -- Included columns only
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS IncludedColumns
    FROM 
        sys.indexes i
    JOIN 
        sys.tables t ON i.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE 
        i.is_primary_key = 0  -- Exclude primary key indexes
        AND i.is_unique = 0    -- Exclude unique indexes
)

SELECT 
    TableName, 
    IndexName, 
    KeyColumns, 
    IncludedColumns
FROM 
    IndexInfo
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM IndexInfo ii
        WHERE ii.TableName = IndexInfo.TableName
        AND ii.KeyColumns = IndexInfo.KeyColumns
        AND ii.IncludedColumns = IndexInfo.IncludedColumns
        AND ii.IndexName <> IndexInfo.IndexName  -- Find duplicate but different indexes
    )
ORDER BY 
    TableName, KeyColumns, IncludedColumns;

I want to get the Index definition with all included columns in the index using SQL query.

Consider adding the SQL tag and also indicating what database you are using.

SELECT i.name AS index_name,COL_NAME(ic.object_id, ic.column_id) AS column_name,ic.is_included_column FROM sys.indexes i INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id WHERE i.object_id = OBJECT_ID('your_table_name');

This SQL query retrieves index details for a specific table:
SELECT i.name AS index_name: Gets each index’s name.
COL_NAME(ic.object_id, ic.column_id) AS column_name: Retrieves each indexed column’s name.
ic.is_included_column: Shows if a column is an "included" (non-key) column.
FROM sys.indexes i: Uses the sys.indexes view.
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic: Matches indexes with their columns.
WHERE i.object_id = OBJECT_ID('your_table_name'): Filters results to a specific table.
Purpose: Shows index structure and columns, helpful for optimizing queries.

Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Please edit your answer, so the details are in the answer itself, and not in a comment on the answer.
